Bug in matplot++ library regarding axis labeling
While using the matplot++ library I noticed that the xlabel and the title are missing (cropped out) from the plots.
Example:
#include <cmath>
#include <matplot/matplot.h>

int main() {
    using namespace matplot;
    std::vector<double> x = linspace(0, 2 * pi);
    std::vector<double> y = transform(x, [](auto x) { return sin(x); });

    plot(x, y, "-o");
    hold(on);
    plot(x, transform(y, [](auto y) { return -y; }), "--xr");
    plot(x, transform(x, [](auto x) { return x / pi - 1.; }), "-:gs");
    plot({ 1.0, 0.7, 0.4, 0.0, -0.4, -0.7, -1 }, "k");
    xlabel("X-axis Label");
    ylabel("Y-axis Label");
    title("My title");
    show();
    return 0;
}

Output:

I really need to add those labels, and I don't want to manually copy the data into Matlab everytime I need a plot.
Thanks for any ideas!

This is a 2 years old bug. Which matplot++ version are you using?

I'm using 1.2.1. I got it from the github page I linked.

I assume you are using the gnuplot backend. This might actually be a gnuplot bug. If you start gnuplot from the command line and try to create a similar graph, does everything work as expected? Also, which version of g up do you use?

If I run the code through the cmd I do get both labels and the title. This is my gnuplot version: gnuplot 6.0 patchlevel 1

@haifisch123 you should use version 5 of gnuplot, 6 is not supported

@ChristianHalaszovich I deleted version 6 and reinstalled 5.4 patchlevel 10. The error is still the same. On its Github it's stated that every version of gnuplot 5.2.6+ is valid: https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus

When I run your code, I get what I'd expect:

Unfortunately, without reproducing the problem, it's hard to give much help.

Did you use Visual Studio to run the code?

No--I ran it on Linux, compiled with g++. It's been a while since I ran Windows often enough to notice, I'm afraid.
